# Prove that the sum of $1/x_k$ is greater than or equal to $n^2$ given that $x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n=1$

Tags: inequality

> Prove that the sum of $\frac{1}{x_k}$ is greater than or equal to $n^2$ given that, $x_i$ is
> a real positive number and $x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n=1$.

I tried by induction but it doesn’t seem to work, I understand that since $f(x)=\frac1x$ is convex and decreasing it makes sense that the minimum is achieved when $z_i=\frac1n$, but I am struggling trying to formalize this concept, could you help, please?

Comment: Have you heard of Jensen's inequality?

Comment: Do you know the AM/GM/HM inequalities?

Comment: Also, are you sure about showing that the sum is less than $n^2$? If you plug in $x_1 = \dots = x_n = 1/n$, then the sum would equal $n^2$. In general, I think the sum is *at least* $n^2$.

Comment: As long as $n>1$ you can always take $x_1=\frac1{n^2+1}$ and adjust the other $n-1$ numbers so that $\sum_{j=2}^n x_j=1-\frac1{n^2+1}$.

Comment: This is an easy consequence of the harmonic-arithmetic mean inequality, and we find $\sum_k x_k^{-1}=n^2$ iff. every $x_k$ is equal to $1/n$

Answer (score 3):

$f(x)=1/x$ is convex on $x>0$. Using [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality), that is

> The value of the average is less than or equal to the average of the values,

we get

$$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}\sum x_i} \leq \frac{1}{n} \sum \frac{1}{x_i},$$

which we can rewrite as

$$\sum \frac{1}{x_i} \geq \frac{n^2}{\sum x_i},$$

which simplifies to

$$\sum \frac{1}{x_i} \geq n^2,$$

if $\sum x_i = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use the AM-GM inequality:
$\dfrac{1}{x_1}+\dfrac{1}{x_2}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{x_n}=\left(\dfrac{1}{x_1}+\dfrac{1}{x_2}+\cdots + \dfrac{1}{x_n}\right)\cdot \left(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n\right)\ge n\cdot\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{1}{x_1x_2\cdots x_n}}\cdot n\cdot \sqrt[n]{x_1x_2\cdots x_n}=n^2$. Equality occurs when $x_1 = x_2 =\cdots = x_n = \dfrac{1}{n}$.